# How to call Web Service when selected option HTML?

Tags: html, web-services, html-select

I have two select option HTML: Category, subCategory, and subCategory must  be dependence of Category ( A item as Category contains many subCategory).

My code to show Category:

```
<select id="categoryID">
          @foreach($category as $item)                
              <option id="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>;                
          @endforeach
        </select>
```

subCategory:

```
<select id="sub_category">
        @foreach($sub_category as $item)              
            <option>{{$item->name}}</option>;              
        @endforeach
      </select>
```

I want to when anyone selected a item in Category, it will call Web service like '/change_category', and return new variable $sub_category dependence ID of Category you selected.

Don't think about function return new variable $sub_category, I just want to ask: How to call Web service when selected option? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="categoryID" onchange="changeCategory(this)">
      @foreach($category as $item)                
          <option id="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>;                
      @endforeach
    </select>


 <script type="text/javascript">             
          function changeCategory(id){
            var category = id[id.selectedIndex].id;                
            $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: url,
                      data: {
                        id: category
                      },
                      success: function (data) {
                       //push data here
                      }
                    });                
          }
        </script>
```